# Checking arrays and implementing bool methods

Tags: ruby, arrays, boolean

You have an array. If any two numbers add to zero in the array, return `true`. It doesn't matter how many pairs there are—as long as there is one pair that adds to zero, return `true`. If there is a zero, it can only return `true` if there is more than one.

I wrote two functions, one to check for each, and a final one to combine both, and return `false` if either aren't met.

```
def checkZero(array)
  zerocount = 0
  for j in 0..array.count
    if array[j] == 0
      zerocount += 1
    end
  end
  if zerocount > 1 #this part seems to not be working, not sure why
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

def checkNegative(array)
  for j in 0..array.count
    neg = -array[j] #set a negative value of the current value
    if array.include?(neg) #check to see whether the negative exists in the array
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end

def checkArray(array)
  if checkZero(array) == true or checkNegative(array) == true
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Then run something like

```
array = [1,2,3,4,0,1,-1]
checkArray(array)
```

So far, Ruby isn't returning anything. I just get a blank. I have a feeling my `return` isn't right.

Comment: For one, don’t use `for` in Ruby. Just use `each`—`for` literally just calls `each` so it’s unidiomatic indirection. Also, in `checkZero` and `checkArray` you can just have the last statement be the conditional, no need to have an `if`. Further, underscored method names are more conventional (e.g. `check_array` instead of `checkArray`). And finally, note that [`and`/`or` is *not* the same as `&&`/`||` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/); only the latter should be used when boolean logic is the intent.

Comment: Oh, and, I can’t reproduce your problem, `checkArray([1,2,3,4,0,1,-1])` returns `true` just fine.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thank you for the tips. Will read up on the difference between and/or and && ||.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you didn't output the result.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,0,1,-1]
puts checkArray(array)
```

The `checkArray` method can be written like the following, if performance (O(*n*^2)) is not a great concern:

```
def check_array(array)
  array.combination(2).any?{|p| p.reduce(:+) == 0}
end
```

The more efficient (O(*n* log *n*)) solution is:

```
def check_array(array)
  array.sort! # `array = array.sort` if you need the original array unchanged
  i, j = 0, array.size - 1
  while i < j
    sum = array[i] + array[j]
    if sum > 0
      j -= 1
    elsif sum < 0
      i += 1
    else
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

Comment: +1 because it is probably the missing `puts` that’s confusing the OP.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the puts, but I did get a lot of great code advice from everyone. Choosing this one as it did solve my problem, the efficient algorithm solution was great too. Thanks

Comment: @cheenbabes You can upvote other helpful answers too, there are some good ones.

Comment: @MarkThomas I tried to do that for your comment and Andrew's, but it said I didn't have enough reputation. I would upvote all of them because they all helped me in different ways, way beyond the scope of just the puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

Here's are a few relatively efficient ways to check if any two values sum to zero:

**Solution #1**

```
def checkit(a)
  return true if a.count(&:zero?) > 1
  b = a.uniq.map(&:abs)
  b.uniq.size < b.size
end
```

**Solution #2**

```
def checkit(a)
  return true if a.sort_by(&:abs).each_cons(2).find { |x,y| x == -y }
  false
end
```

**Solution #3**

```
def checkit(a)
  return true if a.count(&:zero?) > 1
  pos, non_pos = a.group_by { |n| n > 0 }.values
  (pos & non_pos.map { |n| -n }).any?
end
```

**Solution #4**

```
require 'set'

def checkit(a)
  a.each_with_object(Set.new) do |n,s|
    return true if s.include?(-n)
    s << n
  end
  false
end
```

**Examples**

```
checkit([1, 3, 4, 2, 2,-3,-5,-7, 0, 0]) #=> true
checkit([1, 3, 4, 2, 2,-3,-5,-7, 0])    #=> true 
checkit([1, 3, 4, 2,-3, 2,-3,-5,-7, 0]) #=> true
checkit([1, 3, 4, 2, 2,-5,-7, 0])       #=> false
```

**Explanations**

The following all refer to the array:

```
a = [1,3,4,2,2,-3,-5,-7,0]
```

**#1**

Zeroes present a bit of a problem, so lets first see if there are more than one, in which case we are finished. Since `a.count(&:zero?) #=> 1`, `a.count(&:zero?) > 1 #=> false`, so

```
return true if a.count(&:zero?) > 1
```

does not cause us to return. Next, we remove any duplicates:

```
a.uniq                #=> [1, 3, 4, 2, -3, -5, -7, 0]
```

Then convert all the numbers to their absolute values:

```
b = a.uniq,map(&:abs) #=> [1, 3, 4, 2,  3,  5,  7, 0]
```

Lastly see if `c` contains any dups, meaning the original array contained at least two non-zero numbers with opposite signs:

```
c.uniq.size < c.size  #=> true
```

**#2**

```
b = a.sort_by(&:abs)
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, -3, 4, -5, -7]

c = b.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, -3, 4, -5, -7]:each_cons(2)>
```

To see the contents of the enumerator:

```
c.to_a
  #=> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, -3], [-3, 4], [4, -5], [-5, -7]]

c.find { |x,y| x == -y }
  #=> [3, -3]
```

so true is returned.

**#3**

```
return true if a.count(&:zero?) > 1
  #=> return true if 1 > 1

h = a.group_by { |n| n > 0 }
  #=> {true=>[1, 3, 4, 2, 2], false=>[-3, -5, -7, 0]} 
b = h.values 
  #=> [[1, 3, 4, 2, 2], [-3, -5, -7, 0]] 
pos, non_pos = b
pos
  #=> [1, 3, 4, 2, 2]
non_pos
  #=> [-3, -5, -7, 0]
c = non_pos.map { |n| -n }
  #=> [3, 5, 7, 0] 
d = pos & c
  #=> [3] 
d.any?
  #=> true
```

**#4**

```
require 'set'

enum = a.each_with_object(Set.new)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 3, 4, 2, 2, -3, -5, -7, 0]:each_with_object(#<Set: {}>)>
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, #<Set: {}>],
  #    [3, #<Set: {}>],
  #    ...
  #    [0, #<Set: {}>]]
```

Values are passed into the block, assigned to the block variables and the block is executed, as follows:

```
n, s = enum.next
  #=> [1, #<Set: {}>] 
s.include?(-n)
  #=> #<Set: {}>.include?(-1)
  #=> false
s << n
  #=> #<Set: {1}>

n, s = enum.next
  #=> [3, #<Set: {1}>] 
s.include?(-3)
  #=> false 
s << n
  #=> #<Set: {1, 3}> 

...

n, s = enum.next
  #=> [2, #<Set: {1, 3, 4, 2}>] 
s.include?(-n)
  #=> false 
s << n
  #=> #<Set: {1, 3, 4, 2}> # no change

n, s = enum.next
  #=> [-3, #<Set: {1, 3, 4, 2}>] 
s.include?(-n)
  #=> true
```

causing `true` to be returned.

Comment: What about `[1,2,2,3]`?

Comment: Echoing @MarkThomas, I think you must keep positives and negatives separate. Closer to your original answer, though that wasn’t quite right either.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick the original one back!

Comment: @CarySwoveland It still says `[1, 2, 2, 3]` is true, though, but it’s closer to something working. I think the tricky case in splitting, though, is `[0, 0]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is close: `a.partition { |x| x < 0 }.map { |xs| xs.map(&:abs).sort }.reduce(:zip).any?`, but as I suspected it fails on `[0, 0]` since they end up in the same partition.

Comment: Thank you, @Andrew and Mark. It turns out that more was involved than originally thought.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: No problem. This is a great answer now!

Answer (score 1):

I can’t reproduce any problem with your code, but you can express the solution very succinctly using [`combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) to get all possible pairs, then summing each pair with [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), and finally checking if any are [`zero?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Numeric.html#method-i-zero-3F):

```
[1,2,3,4,0,1,-1].combination(2).map { |pair| pair.reduce(:+) }.any?(&:zero?)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing links to the appropriate methods and showing the succinct solution

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Let's start with the first method:

```
def checkZero(array)
```

Ruby naming convention is snake_case rather than camelCase. This should be `def check_zero(array)`

Now the loop:

```
  zerocount = 0
  for j in 0..array.count
    if array[j] == 0
      zerocount += 1
    end
  end
```

As @AndrewMarshall said, `for` is not idiomatic. `each` is preferable. However, in ruby initializing a variable before a loop is almost never needed thanks to all the methods available to you on `Array` and `Enumerable` (which is included in `Array`). I highly recommend committing these methods to memory. The above can be written

```
array.any? {|number| number.zero?}
```

or equivalently

```
array.any?(&:zero?)
```

Now, this part:

```
  if zerocount > 1 #this part seems to not be working, not sure why
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Whenever you have the pattern

```
if (expr that returns true or false)
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

it can be simplified to simply `return (expr that returns true or false)`. And you can even omit the `return` if it is the last statement of a method.

**Putting it all together:**

```
def check_zero(array)
  array.any?(&:zero?)
end

def check_zero_sum(array)
  array.combination(2).any?{|a,b| a + b == 0}
end

def check_array(array)
  check_zero(array) || check_zero_sum(array)
end
```

(Note I borrowed AndrewMarshall's code for `check_zero_sum` which I think is easy to follow, but @CarySwoveland's answer will be faster)

**Edit**

I missed the fact that `check_zero` isn't even necessary because you want at least a pair, in which case `check_zero_sum` is all you need.

```
def check_array(array)
  array.combination(2).any?{|a,b| a + b == 0}
end
```

Comment: `check_zero` is supposed to return true if and only if there is more than one zero. Right now it would return true even if there's only one. Maybe filter and then check the size instead?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I missed that detail! Check_zero isn't even needed then.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thank you! This was really helpful for cleaning up my code and learning. Do all methods that end with `?` return a bool?

Comment: @user2887161 Methods which end with a `?` are called *predicate methods* and while they need not return exactly `true`/`false`, you should only interpret their result as truthy/falsey.

Comment: @cheenbabes They do by convention. Technically, "?" is just a valid character at the end of a method name.